# I'm trying to create a star pyramid which should contain 1 * in the first row, 2* with equal spaces in the second row, like wise 3rd and 4th row

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested-loops

---

```
    [enter image description here][1]
```

- 

### List item

```
    let x = 4;
    let text = "";
    for(let i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
        for(let j = 1; j <= x - i; j++) {
            text += " ";
        }
        for(let k = 0; k < 2 * i - 1; k++) {
        text += "*";
        }
        text +="\n";
    }
    console.log(text);
```

---Output I want is like this. I'm new to this. Thank you in advance
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJvaZ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small change:

```
let x = 4;
let text = "";
for(let i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
    for(let j = 1; j <= x - i; j++) {
        text += " ";
    }
    text += "*";
    for(let k = 0; k + 1 < i; k++) {
        text += " *";
    }
    text +="\n";
}
console.log(text);
```

Comment: for(let k = 0; k + 1 < i; k++) { text += " *"; } -- could you please explain this so that I can understand how this works –

Comment: I just cut the number of iterations in half and added a space in front of the asterisk

Comment: What's confusing for me is on second iteration the value of k is 1 so k + 1 < i is (1+1 < 2) which is false so how it's executing the statement text += " *".  Same doubt on third and fourth iteration

Comment: I finally understood that when the first iteration failed k value is not incremented so on second iteration k value is still 0 so 0+1 < 2 the condition is true so it executes the statement text += "  *". Please correct if I'm wrong.

Comment: For i=2 it runs this loop only once, when k=0. For larger i, it runs it more often.